# Regex: Negative matcher on javascript string ^(?!\\[functional\\]).+$ files fails to exclude [functional]

Tags: regex

In package.json I have 2 script commands:

```
    "test:unit": "jest --watch --testNamePattern='^(?!\\[functional\\]).+$'",
    "test:functional": "jest --watch --testNamePattern='\\[functional\\]'",
```

copying `^(?!\\[functional\\]).+$` into https://regex101.com/, it does not match the test string below inside argument 1 of `describe()`

```
  describe("[functional] live tests", () => {
```

When changed to `([functional]).+$`, the pattern does match. I have to remove a pair of `\` on each end to remove escapes for `.json` files (I think).

Here is what I see when running `npm run test:unit` in my project root:

```
// the functional test runs (not desired)
$ npm run test:unit

 functions/src/classes/__tests__/Functional.test.ts:30:47 - error TS2339: Property 'submit' does not exist on type 'Element'.

    30         await emailForm.evaluate(form => form.submit());
                                                     ~~~~~~

 RUNS  ...s/__tests__/Functional.test.ts
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 skipped, 3 passed, 4 of 5 total
Tests:       2 skipped, 16 passed, 18 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.965s, estimated 27s
Ran all test suites with tests matching "^(?!\[functional\]).+$".

Active Filters: test name /^(?!\[functional\]).+$/
```

The functional tests are not built out which explains the syntax error, it's not important here. The key issue, is why the tests were not skipped.

I believe the problem has to do with the regex negative matcher. The positive matcher without the `!` only matches tests that have, or are nested in a describe block with `[functional]`

```
$ npm run test:functional

Test Suites: 1 failed, 4 skipped, 1 of 5 total
Active Filters: test name /\[functional\]/
```

Anyone know why the negative regex pattern is failing during `npm run test:unit` ?

Comment: `\\` in a string literal represents a single literal ``\``. So, `"^(?!\\[functional\\]).+$"` = `^(?!\[functional\]).+$`. Note you needn't escape `]`

Comment: Phpstorm adds the second set of `\\` in .json files. Also they work for the functional test matcher. But anyways I solved this by using the flag `--testIgnorePattern` and copying the functional test matcher into this flag for the unit test command.

Comment: Good, please post the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a regex fix I changed the flag on the unit testing script to an ignore, then copying the matching pattern for [functional]:

```
"test:unit": "jest --watch --testIgnorePattern='\\[functional\\]'",
"test:functional": "jest --watch --testNamePattern='\\[functional\\]'",
```